# Updating main product url on magento product page

Tags: php, javascript, magento, magento-1.7

I have a probelm with a magento project that I am currently building. My product page has a main image (configurable product) and thumbnails below. I have got my code to the stage where clicking a thumbnail appends the image to the main image area, however i require the href for the link it is contained it to also append to that imgs url. Hope this makes sense, any help welcome.

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>

<div class="grid_12 grid_spacer_bottom">
<?php
    $_img = '<img id="image" class="img-left img-inlineblock responsive-img" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
    //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
?>

<a href=""><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image'); ?></a>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <div class="grid_4 grid_spacer_bottom">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>" onclick="$('image').src = this.href; return false;">
                <img class="img-left img-inlineblock responsive-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think that I have progressed slightly, on the js that updates the img to be displayed as the main image (on the a around the thumbnail) i have tried to add some more js to also update the href for $image and updated the code that builds $image... this still does not append the imgs url though.

onclick="$('image').src = this.href; return false;$('image').href = this.href; return false;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are try to make when you click on the large image it will have the url of the thumbnail

Give this href an ID

```
 <a href="" id="img_href"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image'); ?></a>
```

Are you using jquery or prototype (if default magento then this)

Prototype

```
$('img_href').setAttribute('href', this.href);
//$('img_href').href = this.href; // or
```

jQuery

```
$("#img_href").attr("href", this.href);
```

Plain Javascript

document.getElementById('img_href').href = this.href;

Update the thumbnail onclick

```
onclick="$('image').src = this.href;  $('img_href').setAttribute('href', this.href); return false;"
```

Comment: You legend! I knew I was so close and realised it was something that needed to the onclick function a few minutes ago. 

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

*$('image').parentNode.href='your url';* ?